# How to know when the screen is locked in adobe air on iphone?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, starling-framework, away3d

I am aware of `Stage.ACTIVATE` and `Stage.DEACTIVATE` but this will fire when the app is in background.

Is there a way to know when the device screen is locked, from the background running app and from the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

For screen is locked :

- Add listener to your main class and listen Event.DEACTIVATE
- Add listener to *NativeApplication.nativeApplication* 's instance and listen Event.EXITING

For opening application back :

- Add listener to your main class and listen Event.ACTIVATE

Comment: Deactivate fires when app is in background. Is Is Exit event fired when screen is locked?

Comment: this doesnt work for me, Event.Exiting not firing on lock screen